# Problema al virtualizar máquina virtual

Tags: virtualbox

tengo una máquina virtual en virtual box, la cosa es que cuando intento iniciarla me tira el error guru meditation, investigando me he dado cuenta que pueden ser problemas tales como: poca ram asignada a la máquina, pocos procesadores, la  virtualización no está habilitadad, hyper v está habilitado entre otros menos comunes, sin embargo los anteriores problemas no son mi caso, cuando busco información sobre el erro en el log de la máquina virtual no provee mucha información sobre el error, adjunto información del error, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

**Especificaciones de mi máquina virtual:**

os: oracle linux 6 12 c

4 de ram

2 cores

128 mb de video

**especificaciones de mi pc**

procesador: amd ryzen 3 3200g

apu: vega 8

ram: 16 gb de ram

placa base: asus b450-f

Estoy utilizando la última versión de virtual de box 6.1

```
0:00:03.280309 VMEmt: Halt method global1 (5)
00:00:03.280393 VMEmt: HaltedGlobal1 config: cNsSpinBlockThresholdCfg=50000
00:00:03.280399 Changing the VM state from 'CREATING' to 'CREATED'
00:00:03.281841 Changing the VM state from 'CREATED' to 'POWERING_ON'
00:00:03.281864 AIOMgr: Endpoints without assigned bandwidth groups:
00:00:03.281867 AIOMgr:     D:\bd2\admonbd2\Oracle Linux 6 12C FS_PARA_ABD\OracleLinux-disk2.vdi
00:00:03.281869 AIOMgr:     D:\bd2\admonbd2\Oracle Linux 6 12C FS_PARA_ABD\Oracle Linux 6 12C FS-disk1.vdi
00:00:03.281990 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_ON' to 'RUNNING'
00:00:03.282006 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
00:00:03.287649 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: VirtualBox 6.1.18
00:00:03.287871 PCI: Setting up resources and interrupts
00:00:03.294655 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_VM_ERROR (0x80bb0003) aIID={4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={Could not take a screenshot (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-37
00:00:03.294742 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:03.318050 VMMDev: Guest Log: CPUID EDX: 0x178bfbff
00:00:03.318700 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: RESET, DevSel=0 AIOIf=0 CmdIf0=0x00 (-1 usec ago) CmdIf1=0x00 (-1 usec ago)
00:00:03.318784 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:03.324837 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:03.326032 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:03.326043 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:03.326047 VD#1: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:03.326402 AHCI#0: Port 0 reset
00:00:03.326454 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:03.327728 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: AHCI 0-P#0: PCHS=16383/16/63 LCHS=1024/255/63 0x0000000007800000 sectors
00:00:03.328117 AHCI#0: Port 1 reset
00:00:03.328155 VD#1: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:03.329276 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: AHCI 1-P#1: PCHS=16383/16/63 LCHS=1024/255/63 0x0000000006400000 sectors
00:00:03.335633 PIT: mode=2 count=0x48d3 (18643) - 64.00 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:03.346337 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000cd50000 w=640 h=480 bpp=32 cbLine=0xA00 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:03.782195 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 400x229
00:00:03.790247 GUI: 2D video acceleration is disabled
00:00:03.790442 GUI: HID LEDs sync is enabled
00:00:03.812103 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:05.818576 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:05.821656 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:05.822248 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=1, bootseq=0231
00:00:05.822678 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:05.823124 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=2, bootseq=0023
00:00:05.824256 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: CDROM boot failure code : 0003
00:00:05.824592 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from CD-ROM failed
00:00:05.825040 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=3, bootseq=0002
00:00:05.826206 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from Hard Disk...
00:00:05.830729 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=82
00:00:05.831366 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 08, unmapped device for ELDL=82
00:00:05.861572 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000cd50000 w=640 h=480 bpp=0 cbLine=0x140 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:10.287062 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:11.157765 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: KBD: unsupported int 16h function 03
00:00:11.158182 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: AX=0305 BX=0000 CX=0000 DX=0000 
00:00:11.170351 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=82
00:00:11.170962 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=82
00:00:11.171587 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=83
00:00:11.172174 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=83
00:00:11.172798 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=84
00:00:11.173398 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=84
00:00:11.174031 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=85
00:00:11.174615 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=85
00:00:11.175243 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=86
00:00:11.175828 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=86
00:00:11.176451 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=87
00:00:11.177080 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=87
00:00:11.177706 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=88
00:00:11.178294 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=88
00:00:11.178946 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=89
00:00:11.179531 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=89
00:00:11.180158 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=8a
00:00:11.180747 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=8a
00:00:11.181371 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=8b
00:00:11.181957 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=8b
00:00:11.182583 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=8c
00:00:11.183168 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=8c
00:00:11.183804 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=8d
00:00:11.184384 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=8d
00:00:11.185013 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=8e
00:00:11.185609 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=8e
00:00:11.186233 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk_ext: function 41, unmapped device for ELDL=8f
00:00:11.186822 VMMDev: Guest Log: int13_harddisk: function 02, unmapped device for ELDL=8f
00:00:12.429679 PIT: mode=2 count=0x4a9 (1193) - 1000.15 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:12.502711 MsrExit/0: 0010:ffffffff810473a6/LM: RDMSR 00000403 -> 00000000 / VERR_CPUM_RAISE_GP_0
00:00:12.512670 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'GURU_MEDITATION'
00:00:12.512703 Console: Machine state changed to 'GuruMeditation'
00:00:12.512902 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:12.512903 !!
00:00:12.512903 !!         VCPU0: Guru Meditation 1155 (VINF_EM_TRIPLE_FAULT)
00:00:12.512912 !!
00:00:12.512915 !! Skipping ring-0 registers and stack, rcErr=VINF_EM_TRIPLE_FAULT
00:00:12.512919 !!
00:00:12.512919 !! {mappings, <NULL>}
00:00:12.512919 !!
00:00:12.512928 !!
00:00:12.512928 !! {hma, <NULL>}
00:00:12.512928 !!
00:00:12.512929 Hypervisor Memory Area (HMA) Layout: Base 00000000a0000000, 0x02800000 bytes
00:00:12.512932 00000000a1090000-00000000a109e000 000000000a260000 ffff9a06bb1cc000 LOCKED                   alloc once (VMM)
00:00:12.512936 00000000a028f000-00000000a1090000 000000000ade0000 ffffcffd61400000 LOCKED                   alloc once (PGM_PHYS)
00:00:12.512939 00000000a0224000-00000000a028f000 000000000ad70000 ffff9a06c8e02000 LOCKED                   alloc once (PGM_POOL)
00:00:12.512942 00000000a0223000-00000000a0224000 000000000a200000 ffff9a06bb174000 LOCKED                   alloc once (CPUM_CTX)
00:00:12.512945 00000000a0023000-00000000a0223000 000000000ab70000 ffffcffd61000000 LOCKED                   Heap
00:00:12.512947 00000000a000e000-00000000a0023000 000000000a160000 ffff9a06bb133000 LOCKED                   VMCPU
00:00:12.512949 00000000a0000000-00000000a000e000 00000000042c0000 ffff9a06bb123000 LOCKED                   VM
00:00:12.512951 !!
00:00:12.512952 !! {cpumguest, verbose}
00:00:12.512953 !!
00:00:12.512956 Guest CPUM (VCPU 0) state: 
00:00:12.512959 rax=000000008159312c rbx=0000000000000001 rcx=ffffffff8159312c rdx=0000000000000000
00:00:12.512961 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=ffffffff8159b2b8 r8 =0000000000000000 r9 =ffffffff81899d68
00:00:12.512962 r10=0000000081899e98 r11=0000000000000092 r12=00000000ffffffff r13=ffffffff810473a6
00:00:12.512963 r14=ffffffff81899e54 r15=0000000000000403
00:00:12.512964 rip=ffffffff81593370 rsp=ffff88011fc04000 rbp=ffffffff81593370 iopl=0         nv up di pl zr ac pe cy
00:00:12.512965 cs={0010 base=0000000000000000 limit=ffffffff flags=0000209b}
00:00:12.512966 ds={0000 base=0000000000000000 limit=ffffffff flags=00000000}
00:00:12.512967 es={0000 base=0000000000000000 limit=ffffffff flags=00000000}
00:00:12.512968 fs={0000 base=0000000000000000 limit=ffffffff flags=00000000}
00:00:12.512968 gs={0000 base=0000000000000000 limit=ffffffff flags=00000000}
00:00:12.512969 ss={0000 base=0000000000000000 limit=ffffffff flags=00004000}
00:00:12.512970 cr0=000000008005003b cr2=0000000000000001 cr3=00000000018a4000 cr4=00000000000006f0
00:00:12.512971 dr0=0000000000000000 dr1=0000000000000000 dr2=0000000000000000 dr3=0000000000000000
00:00:12.512971 dr4=0000000000000000 dr5=0000000000000000 dr6=00000000ffff0ff0 dr7=0000000000000400
00:00:12.512972 gdtr=ffff88011fc04000:007f  idtr=ffffffff81b4f000:0fff  eflags=00000013
00:00:12.512974 ldtr={0000 base=00000000 limit=0000ffff flags=00000000}
00:00:12.512974 tr  ={0040 base=ffff88011fc11bc0 limit=00002087 flags=0000008b}
00:00:12.512975 SysEnter={cs=0010 eip=000000008159cc60 esp=0000000000000000}
00:00:12.512988 xcr=0000000000000001 xcr1=0000000000000000 xss=0000000000000000 (fXStateMask=0000000000000000)
00:00:12.512990 FCW=037f FSW=0000 FTW=0000 FOP=0000 MXCSR=00001f80 MXCSR_MASK=0002ffff
00:00:12.512991 FPUIP=00000000 CS=0000 Rsrvd1=0000  FPUDP=00000000 DS=0000 Rsvrd2=0000
00:00:12.512993 ST(0)=FPR0={0000'00000000'00000000} t0 +0.0000000000000000000000 * 2 ^ -16383 (*)
00:00:12.512997 ST(1)=FPR1={0000'00000000'00000000} t0 +0.0000000000000000000000 * 2 ^ -16383 (*)
00:00:12.512999 ST(2)=FPR2={0000'00000000'00000000} t0 +0.0000000000000000000000 * 2 ^ -16383 (*)
00:00:12.513001 ST(3)=FPR3={0000'00000000'00000000} t0 +0.0000000000000000000000 * 2 ^ -16383 (*)
00:00:12.513003 ST(4)=FPR4={0000'00000000'00000000} t0 +0.0000000000000000000000 * 2 ^ -16383 (*)
00:00:12.513005 ST(5)=FPR5={0000'00000000'00000000} t0 +0.0000000000000000000000 * 2 ^ -16383 (*)
00:00:12.513007 ST(6)=FPR6={0000'00000000'00000000} t0 +0.0000000000000000000000 * 2 ^ -16383 (*)
00:00:12.513009 ST(7)=FPR7={0000'00000000'00000000} t0 +0.0000000000000000000000 * 2 ^ -16383 (*)
00:00:12.513011 XMM0 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000  XMM1 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000
00:00:12.513014 XMM2 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000  XMM3 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000
00:00:12.513016 XMM4 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000  XMM5 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000
00:00:12.513018 XMM6 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000  XMM7 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000
00:00:12.513020 XMM8 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000  XMM9 =00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000
00:00:12.513022 XMM10=00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000  XMM11=00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000
00:00:12.513024 XMM12=00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000  XMM13=00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000
00:00:12.513026 XMM14=00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000  XMM15=00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000
00:00:12.513029 EFER         =0000000000000d01
00:00:12.513029 PAT          =0007010600070106
00:00:12.513030 STAR         =0023001000000000
00:00:12.513030 CSTAR        =ffffffff8159ce90
00:00:12.513031 LSTAR        =ffffffff8159b6a0
00:00:12.513031 SFMASK       =0000000000043700
00:00:12.513032 KERNELGSBASE =ffff88011fc00000
00:00:12.513053 !!
00:00:12.513053 !! {cpumguesthwvirt, verbose}
00:00:12.513053 !!
00:00:12.513058 VCPU[0] hardware virtualization state:
00:00:12.513059 fLocalForcedActions          = 0x0
00:00:12.513060 No/inactive hwvirt state
00:00:12.513061 !!
00:00:12.513061 !! {cpumguestinstr, verbose}
00:00:12.513062 !!
00:00:12.513086 
00:00:12.513086 CPUM0: 0010:ffffffff81593370 c0 33 59                sal byte [rbx], 059h
00:00:12.513086 
00:00:12.513088 !!
00:00:12.513088 !! {cpumhyper, verbose}
00:00:12.513088 !!
00:00:12.513090 Hypervisor CPUM state: 
00:00:12.513091 .dr0=0000000000000000 .dr1=0000000000000000 .dr2=0000000000000000 .dr3=0000000000000000
00:00:12.513092 .dr4=0000000000000000 .dr5=0000000000000000 .dr6=0000000000000000 .dr7=0000000000000000
00:00:12.513093 CR4OrMask=0x204 CR4AndMask=0x403
00:00:12.513094 !!
```

Comment: Estoy removiendo la etiqueta [oracle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info), pues no tiene nada que ver con ella. Esta etiqueta es para el gestor de base de datos, no es un mega-contenedor para todos los productos de la empresa oracle.

Comment: Por otro lado, en el log solo se ve un error. Hice una búsqueda en google con el código de error y me llevó a [esto](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=99437), que no se si te sirva, en todo caso, no olvides que google es tu amigo. Un saludo.

Comment: Sobre qué os, con qué procesador y con que configuración estás iniciando esa VM? QUé versión de virtualbox?

Comment: saludos, me disculpo, no puse la información de la máquina virtual ni la de mi pc, ya edité mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a mi problema, el mensaje de guru de metitation es un error que puede tener muchas causas por lo que encontrar la solución que diera con mi problema fue una tarea un poco difícil pero al final es cuestión de perseverar. En el caso de que alguien tenga este mismo problema y no haya dado con una solución les dejo la mía.

**Pasos que hice para solucionarlo**

1.Entrar a programas y caraterísticas de windows

2.Desinstalar windows subsystem for linux

3.entrar al cmd con privilegios de admin

4.ejecutar `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

5.reiniciar el pc y listo

Esta fue mi solución, hay que tener cuidado ya que este tipo de error parece ser muy genérico y no te dice nada sobre el origen del problema.Al menos en mi caso ni siquiera me mostraba el error en el vbox.log